# Apply multiple filters using the URL in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I am just starting out with KeystoneJS. I have set up a section "items" and these have multiple relationships in it such as "manufacturer", "type", "category", etc.

While out of the box with Keystone you can filter by any one of these, I want to be able to filter by multiple params using the URL - e.g.

`www.site.com/category/blinds/manufacturer/orion/`
or 
`www.site.com/manufacturer/orion/type/venetian`

Can anyone bump me in the right direction for how to accomplish this in keystone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/manufacturer/:manufact/category/:category/type/:type',function(req,res) {
  var mymanufacturer= req.params.manufact;
  var mycat= req.params.category;
  var my type =  req.params.type;
});
```

But the issue is that you must provide both category and type. So you can not use your 2nd url. for that you have to have categor like this.

```
www.site.com/manufacturer/orion/category/all/type/venetian
```

Instead  You can use  URL query like this

www.site.com?manufacturer=orion?category=blank&type= venetian

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var mymanufacturer= req.query.manufacture;
  var mycat= req.query.category;
  var my type =  req.query.type;
});
```